# How to open/close keyboard of android phone using javascript/angular

Tags: javascript, android, html, angular

Is there a way in which I can open or close the keyboard on Android mobile using Javascript or angular 4

Comment: You can probably create an `<input>` and set the focus to it to trick the browser to open up the keyboard, but that is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: If you are using phonegap you can use this here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/How-to-show-and-hide-soft-keyboard-in-Android

Comment: No we are not using Phonegap, and is there any way to do it with the help of javascript